# Bluez libraries cause a lot of problems

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, bluez, cstdint

I'm trying to compile a C++ project on raspberry pi B+ in codeblocks. Code is taken from [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    inquiry_info *li = NULL;
    int max_rsp, num_rsp;
    int dev_id, sock, len, flags;
    int i;
    char addr[19] = {0};
    char name[248] = {0};

    dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
    sock = hci_open_dev(dev_id);
    if(dev_id < 0||sock < 0)
    {
        perror("opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    len=8;
    max_rsp = 255;
    flags = IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH;
    li = (inquiry_info*)malloc(max_rsp * sizeof(inquiry_info));

    num_rsp = hci_inquiry(dev_id, len, max_rsp, NULL, &li, flags);
    if(num_rsp) perror("hci_inquiry");

    for(i = 0; i < num_rsp; i++)
    {
        ba2str(&(li+i)->bdaddr, addr);
        memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
        if(hci_read_remote_name(sock, &(li+i)->bdaddr, sizeof(name), name, 0) < 0) strcpy(name, "[unknown]");
        printf("%s %s\n", addr, name);
    }

    free(li);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

GCC 4.6 with [std=c++0x] flag gives me the next errors:

```
/home/pi/bluez-5.11/lib/bluetooth/hci.h|315|error: ‘uint8_t’ does not name a type|
/home/pi/bluez-5.11/lib/bluetooth/hci.h|316|error: ‘uint8_t’ does not name a type|
/home/pi/bluez-5.11/lib/bluetooth/hci.h|317|error: ‘uint8_t’ does not name a type|
/home/pi/bluez-5.11/lib/bluetooth/hci.h|322|error: ‘uint8_t’ does not name a type|
/home/pi/bluez-5.11/lib/bluetooth/hci.h|323|error: ‘bdaddr_t’ does not name a type|
/home/pi/bluez-5.11/lib/bluetooth/hci.h|331|error: ‘uint16_t’ does not name a type|
/home/pi/bluez-5.11/lib/bluetooth/hci.h|332|error: ‘uint16_t’ does not name a type|
```

As you can see I have `<cstdint>` and `using namespace std` lines. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'd guess you need to include `stdint.h` rather than `cstdint`, to make the `uint32_t` et al. work within the `#include <bluetooth/hci.h>` include statement. (there's most probably no `using namespace std;`)

Comment: `stdint.h` gives no result, adding `using namespace std;` to `hci.h` gives no result too.

Comment: You should not type  `using namespace std;`. (almost ever) and certainly not when it is completely useless : you don't use anything from the std namespace in your entire code here.. It is a really bad habit people have in trivial tutorial program. Everybody compies it and it's just bad practice.

Comment: compiled your code on raspberri-pi with the same compiler without any errors: g++ -std=c++0x bl.cc   -lbluetooth Apparently you haven't installed libbluetooth-dev and in the process of configuring your unpacked /home/pi/bluez-5.11 made some mishap with code and compilation flags.